# Cheap and robust all-round tablet for running developed applications

Tags: android, recommendation-engine

This question doesn't suit https://android.stackexchange.com/.

Which of the low-budget (< 200€) tablet devices would you recommend as being the best compromise in terms of features and the most robust ? This is to run custom created-on-demand software (personal apps, commercial...). I am in Europe.

Comment: The android tag here is for android _development_, not android tablet recommendations. Sorry, but you won't find an answer here.

Comment: Yes, but you have to help a man out don't you? Next time try forums though and Google

Comment: @user1536486 Understood. This is obviously a grey area where the question doesn't fit. I would prefer to have feedback from a developer though.

Comment: Well, I have a kindle fire and I like that a lot. It works more as a tablet than an e-reader in my opinion.

Comment: Ok. I should probably stick to Android though as I mostly familiar with Java. One request would involve making a custom address book so @Peter's suggestion might be overkill. However, I might as well find out which device would suit as a good all-rounder.

Comment: @JamesPoulson Kindle fire is Android, but heavily modded. I don't know if you will be good to go to develop there. The new Kindle fire should be at nexus 7's levels maybe a little better(to hit the competition), but we don't know release date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus 7 I guess is the best under this price. It has 4 cores decent memory and I don't think you will never need over 25 GB storage with Dropbox/GDrive/Box(50GB)/Skydrive. It has 4.1 Jellybean and

Comment: Thank you. You were meaning to add something ? Also I'm open to any recommendations for a good android site where this question could have been better asked. Google gives a mix of reviews on devices but I'm new to the platform and not sure what characteristics I should look out for.

Comment: Believe me for 200$ this is the best

Yes I don't know why the rest was cropped out. 

I was going to add that it is a clean install of Android and you should expect for support from Google and other things which i forgot. 
You should be looking for CPU and RAM, then the manufacturer and his reputation with updates. Internal memory and finally the screen.

Some things are quite the same in most devices, so I minimized to the most important